# Restkit post operation is successful and returns expected JSON data, but mappingResult array is empty

Tags: arrays, json, response, restkit-0.20

I suspect that my response Descriptors need work.  I have been reviewing the ObjectMapping document on RestKit Wiki.  I have defined classes for myitem the details of an array object and Items all objects in the array

Restkit successfully posts but returns empty array as mappingResult array...How do I get to the JSON data returned?  I had found some code from earlier version of Restkit but it may not work now.  How do I get to the JSON response object that is return so that I can parse it myself?

```
RKResponseDescriptor *itemsDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:myItemsMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"myItems" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
    RKResponseDescriptor *itemDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:itemMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:@"/item" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:itemsDescriptor];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:itemDescriptor];
```

Comment: If you want to do the mapping yourself then you don't use RestKit, just use AFNetworking. Is this the same as your previous question? Need more details to resolve the issue...

Comment: @Wain Yes, it is the same question. Each time, I'm more successful in get the desired output from RestKit.  I know the issue is how to map the response that I'm getting back within the Restkit  Framework. I thank you for responding.  You have been helpful Thanks again.